# How to specify a target element with on events combined in an object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I want to specify a target element for a single jQuery event, I do it like this:

```
$(".foo").on("click", ".foo-child", function(...));
```

Where `.foo-child` is my target element. But how do I specify target elements for several events combined in an object?

```
$(".foo").on({
    click: function(...),
    hover: function(...),
    focus: function(...)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the dynamic element selector as the second parameter like

```js
$(".foo").on({
  click: function() {
    snippet.log('click')
  },
  mouseenter: function(e) {
    snippet.log('mouseenter ')
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
    snippet.log('mouseleave ')
  },
  focus: function() {
    snippet.log('focus')
  }
}, '.foo-child');
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="foo-child">1</div>
  <div class="foo-child">2</div>
  <div class="foo-child">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it can only be one target element for all events. I mean I can't specify several targets different for every event?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
$("foobar").on({
    mouseenter: function() {

    },
    mouseleave: function() {

    },
    click: function() {

    }
}, "body");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I misplaced the handler and selector in the previous comment. Here is the working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/1jzwsn3z/ `here`

Answer (score 0):

> how do I specify target elements for several events combined in an object?

There's no need to make a single call to `on` and specify multiple different event+target pairs as you can just call `on` multiple times using chaining:

```
$(".foo")
    .on("click", ".foo-child-click", function(...))
    .on("hover", ".foo-child-hover", function(...))
    .on("focus", ".foo-child-focus", function(...));
```

You can specify multiple targets per event, eg:

```
$(".foo")
    .on("click", ".foo-child-click,.foo-child-hover,.foo-child-focus", function(...))
```